# How to build a RESTEasy project with Maven?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

### Context

I am trying to create a project that publishes JAX-RS web services with JBoss Developer Studio 8.0.0 GA and Wildfly 8.2.0.Final with the built-in RESTEasy 3.0.10.Final library.

### The phenomenon

When I create a Dynamic Web Project with the default settings plus web.xml creation, add a package named com.example with the two classes below, add the project to the application server, the REST service works fine when I access it using a browser (URL: `http://localhost:8080/RestTest/rest/resttest/test`), displaying the `Hello REST` message as expected.

However, when I convert the project to a Maven project by right clicking the project and choosing Configure / Convert to Maven Project and using the default settings (and then removing the picketbox-related dependecies from pom.xml), the REST service does not work after publishing, and got a `Not Found` error message in the browser instead.

The two classes are the following:

**com/example/RestApp.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApp extends Application
{ }
```

**com/example/RestEndpoint.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@RequestScoped
@Path("/resttest")
public class RestEndpoint
{
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public String test()
    {
        return "Hello REST";
    }

}
```

**The generated pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId>
      <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RestTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### Question

What goes wrong with the conversion? How can I build the project with Maven so that it works?

Comment: how does your web.xml looks like after converting to maven?

Comment: Please also post the generate pom.xml, you may also want to look at the output of the WAR file.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding the generated pom.xml and web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of work I finally found the solution: if I **remove all the resteasy-related dependencies except for org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs-api**, the application will work.

No web.xml is needed at all, I deleted it.

The minimal pom.xml required for the working REST service looks like follows:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>RestTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your web.xml is missing resteasy servlet config.. Compare it with the one it's working, see if there are any differences..

EDIT: According to http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e40 it should work without configuring the web.xml, so my answer is not correct.

By the way, your pom has many dependencies which should be scope provided (if I'm not mistaken, all of them should be provided, beacuse wildfly has them).